# MapView.zoomToBoundingBox() not zooming

Tags: osmdroid

I'm trying to zoom the map to a specific bounding box. I know I have to make the call AFTER the layout of the map is ready, so that is not the problem. The camera only gets centered on the bounding box, but it doesn't zoom as closely as possible, it just stays at whatever zoom level was set previously. What am I missing? How do I make it zoom as well?

Answer (score 0):

The class [MapController](http://osmdroid.azurewebsites.net/osmdroid-android-4.3-javadoc/index.html) in the API allows to move and animate the map. Maybe you can look the `zoomToSpan`method.